# HttpContext.GetOwinContext() does not contain definition for GetOwinContext()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this error on my Controller, 'HttpContextBase does not contain definition for GetOwinContext and no accessible extension method GetOwinContext accepting a first argument of a type HttpContextBase'. The question is how do i now solve this issue? The namespace and assembly are being defined here below already. Is there something else i should have done to avoid this error? Please advice and help me further, thanks.

```
 // ManageController.cs

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
    using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
    using eNtsaTrainingRegistration.Models;

    namespace eNtsaTrainingRegistration.Controllers
    {
        [Authorize]
        public class ManageController : AppBaseController
        {
            private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
            private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
            private ApplicationRoleManager _roleManager;

            // default constructor.

            public ManageController()
            {

            }
            public ManageController(ApplicationSignInManager signInManager, ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationRoleManager roleManager)
            {
                UserManager = userManager;
                SignInManager = signInManager;
                AppRoleManager = roleManager;
            }
            public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
            {
                get
                {
                    return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()// Error is here;
                }
                private set
                {
                    _userManager = value;
                }
            }

            public ApplicationRoleManager AppRoleManager
            {
                get
                {
                    return _roleManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationRoleManager>();
                }
            }


        }


    }

//IdentityConfig.cs

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Security.Claims;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
    using Microsoft.Owin;
    using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
    using System.Net.Mail;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Web.Configuration;
    using eNtsaTrainingRegistration.Models;

    namespace eNtsaTrainingRegistration
    {
        public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
        {
            public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
            {
                var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
                mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(message.Destination));
                mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("Gcobani Mkontwana <ggcobani@gmail.com>");
                mailMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mailMessage.Body = message.Body;

                using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    var credential = new NetworkCredential
                    {
                        UserName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"],
                        Password = Helper_b.Decrypt(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserPassword"])
                    };
                    smtp.Credentials = credential;
                    smtp.Host = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPName"];
                    smtp.Port = int.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPPort"]);
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtp.Send(mailMessage);
                }
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }

        public class SmsService : IIdentityMessageService
        {
            public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
            {
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }
        // add another method here.
        public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
        {
            public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
                : base(store)
            {
            }

            public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
            {
                var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
                // Configure validation logic for usernames
                manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
                {
                    AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                    RequireUniqueEmail = true
                };

                // Configure validation logic for passwords
                manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
                {
                    RequiredLength = 6,
                    RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
                    RequireDigit = true,
                    RequireLowercase = true,
                    RequireUppercase = true,
                };

                // Configure user lockout defaults
                manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
                manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

                // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
                // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
                manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
                {
                    MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
                });
                manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
                {
                    Subject = "Security Code",
                    BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
                });
                manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
                manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
                var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
                if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
                {
                    manager.UserTokenProvider =
                        new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
                }
                return manager;
            }
        }
        // SignInManager class.
        public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
        {
            public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
            : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
            {
            }

            public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
            {
                return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
            }

            public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
            {
                return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
            }
        }
        public class ApplicationRoleManager:RoleManager<IdentityRole>
        {
            public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string> roleStore)
                :base(roleStore)
            {

            }
            public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
            {
                var appRoleManager = new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));

                return appRoleManager;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do i resolve now this error?

Answer (score 0):

`GetOwinContext` is en extension of `HttpContext` and not `HttpContextBase`. Try this:

```
HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context.GetOwinContext()...
```

Comment: It doe not work, i will include IdentifyConfig.cs. All those members are accessed directly from this class. Therefore Controller will reference them as object and  casting.

Comment: IdentifyConfig? You asked about how to call the extension method, didn't you? You need an instance of an `HttpContext` to call it.

Comment: Something like this?    public ApplicationRoleManager AppRoleManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _roleManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationRoleManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _roleManager = value;
            }
        }

Comment: @Luks10Mkontwana: `return _userManager ?? HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();`

Comment: GetOwinContext() is not accessible when i make a return.

Comment: @You didn't install [Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb) then?

Comment: mm8 yes mate, but after i did and error was gone happy development. Thanks

Comment: @Luks10Mkontwana: Please remember to accept the answer if your issue has been solved.

Answer (score -1):

Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb